# Why didn't the Ferengi Commerce Authority take Quark's mother's house and possessions?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

> BRUNT: Of course there is. You can break the contract.
>
> QUARK: Me, break a Ferengi contract? Never.
>
> BRUNT: Never? I wonder if there's enough Ferengi left in you to stick to that. Part of me hopes you will break it because then everything you and your family own on Ferenginar will be confiscated and sold to the lowest bidder. **Your mother will be forced to live in the streets, begging for scraps of food** and of course no Ferengi will do business with you, or even talk to you. You'll be cut off from all contact with your own people.
>
> QUARK: I like Ferengi. I feel comfortable around them.
>
> BRUNT: Well, we don't feel comfortable around you. You're a disease, Quark. A festering tumour on the lobes of Ferengi society. And it's my job to cut you off.

DS9 "Ferengi Love Songs":

> ISHKA: Quark?
>
> QUARK: Mother?  (She lets him in.)
>
> QUARK: Moogie, hold me.

So Quark's mom still has her home and is doing quite well.

> QUARK: I had no place else to go.
>
> ISHKA: Are you sure about that? Oh, now don't give me that look. You
> and I both know we've never really gotten along. You disapprove of me,
> Quark. You always have. Moogie, stop wearing clothes. Moogie, stop
> earning profit.
>
> QUARK: **You have stopped, haven't you?** I mean earning profit. Wearing
> clothes is bad enough, but profit.
>
> ISHKA: **You see what I mean?**

So Quark's mom is alive and well and not on the streets. (And dating the Grand Nagus to boot.)

After Quark breaks the contract the FCA should have seized all of Quark's things including his mother's possessions. She should have been out on the streets as Brunt stated. This all happened well before she was dating the Nagus so it couldn't have been him who protected her.

Why was she allowed to keep her possessions?

Comment: @Praxis Ha Ha, lol. It was a long weekend. I think between the girls and the hot tub and lack of sleep anything I write here will have to be edited.

Comment: No worries, just wanted you to know why.  Sounds like you had a crazy weekend, lol!

Comment: @Praxis I always have a crazy weekend it seems. This one was tamer then most! I've actually got a model gf, that likes other girls, and will watch Star Trek with me, lol. She actually says I want to see Janeway! But she hates 7 of 9 for some reason. So I absolutely cannot laugh, make mention, or talk about her at all even if she is in her 50's now.

Comment: Sounds like you lead an interesting life, my friend!  :-)

Comment: Do we ever see Brunt and Ishka interact on stage?

Comment: @zwol sure, the first time Quark goes home to his mom, she greets him and his bro, and then Brunt walks into the house. He's pissed that she's clothed, if memory serves correctly. I'm not going to look up the episode, etc. Don't have time like that anymore.

Answer (score 6):

I think there are two possibilities; either Ishka was already dating the Grand Nagus, or Brunt was bluffing when he threatened Quark's mother.

Ishka could have been dating the Grand Nagus by that point.  I don't recall an on-screen confirmation of how long the two were dating before "Ferengi Love Songs."  This is the only dialog I found that could reference when they met:

> QUARK: How did you two meet?
>
> ISHKA: We met at the Global Tongo Championships.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is another reference to the Global Tongo Championships (there's no way to know what time of year they take place), so it isn't possible to know if they began dating in late 2372 (approximately the same time as "Body Parts") or in early 2373 (closer to when Quark visited in "Ferengi Love Songs").  We know that the two episodes are separated by months, but we don't know how many months because there is no stardate associated with "Ferengi Love Songs."  If Ishka was dating the Grand Nagus by the time Brunt tried to kick her out onto the street, the Grand Nagus could easily have bought the house and returned it to Ishka.

Brunt might have been bluffing when he threatened Ishka.  I don't recall Rom getting declared persona non grata.  Admittedly, Rom didn't own very much, and maybe Brunt simply ignored him, but you would think Brunt would harass ALL of Quark's family members, especially one who was right there next to Quark.  If Brunt spared Rom, it wouldn't be surprising for him to spare Ishka.  From "Body Parts," where it appears Rom was spared Brunt's inquisition:

> ROM: How are you, brother?
>
> QUARK: How am I? I'm broke. Ruined. Destitute. A pariah. How are things with you?
>
> ROM: Not bad.
>
> QUARK: Glad to hear it.
>
> ROM: They took everything?
>
> QUARK: Including this shirt. I'm supposed to send it to Brunt in the morning.
>
> ROM: Don't worry. I have some old clothes I was going to throw out.
>
> QUARK: I'd rather be naked.

And there's always the remote chance that Brunt's sadistic love of auditing other Ferengi doesn't extend to evicting poor old widows.

Comment: If I were Brunt, I would have left Rom alone just to make Quark feel worse about himself. Considering the relationship between Quark and his mother, that logic might hold there as well

Comment: Considering Ferengi women are property, and Quark is the eldest male, I bet ferengi law considers her mother's house and clothes to belong to Quark, hence the legal threat. Rom being able to own property legally, would not be a legal target

Comment: "And there's always the remote chance that Brunt's sadistic love of auditing other Ferengi doesn't extend to evicting poor old widows." I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @Zibbohz especially since Quark stated on many occasions that it's perfectly reasonable for Ferengi to "Sell their own mother", if it can yield a profit. It's even in the Ferengi Rules of Acquisition, IIRC.